# Почему "биткоин", а не "биткойн"?

Tags: заимствования, транскрипция, неологизмы, транслитерация

Я понимаю, что это один из самых свежих неологизмов в русском языке, но мне все равно интересно: есть ли какое-нибудь объяснение, почему везде прижилось написание *биткоин*, а не *биткойн*? [Русская википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD) чуть ли не единственный ресурс, где пишут "бикойн" через "й". И в этой же статье на википедии написано, что сосуществуют и транскрипция «Биткойн», и транслитерация «Биткоин». Более того, про транскрипцию написано:

> Транскрипция «Биткойн», соответствующая правилам англо-русской практической транскрипции, используемой для передачи английских собственных имён, а также других лексических единиц, непосредственно заимствуемых из английского (например, терминов), для которых не существует исторически сложившейся (традиционной) передачи на русский язык языка…

Транскрипция гораздо логичней — ведь в ней, как и в исходном английском слове "Bitcoin" два слога, а не три, как в "биткоин". Но почему тогда практически везде пишется "биткоин"? И кстати, а как его люди произносят?

Comment: Вообще-то, ближе к реальной транскрипции и будет И. В английском-то произношении нет йота в этом слове. Некоторые из этих правил транскрипций тоже не всегда понятно, на чём основываются.

Comment: Да и при записи фонетичекой транскрипции видно, что дифтонг составлен из раздельных звуков [-ɔɪ-], которые не образуют нового - не важно, как здесь подсчитывать количество слогов.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой: При всем уважении, по-моему, "английском-то произношении нет йота" и "видно, что дифтонг составлен из раздельных звуков" -- это не аргумент. Просто потому, что вы его избирательно применили только к этому слову. Я вообще не могу припомнить ни одного заимствования или кальки, где бы в сходном дифтонге по-русски появилась бы "и", а не "й". `Спойлер`, `бройлер`, `мерчендайзер` (прости, господи), и даже на ту же тему `блокчейн` -- везде "й".

Comment: @Alex_ander: А я всегда считал, что дифтонг -- это таки новый звук, хоть и состоящий из двух частей. А то, что его принято такими значкам записывать -- дело вторичное.

Comment: Zipirovich, Вы бы хоть цитировали нормально. Ваши примеры как раз несходные кроме "блокчейна". В других этот дифтонг не в последнем слоге. А примеры, пожалуйста: *коллоид, Андроид*. Правда вот Pink FLoyd по-русски из них выбивается, надо признать.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой: Фигуральное "-1" за ваше высокомерное "Вы бы хоть цитировали нормально". Второе "-1" за ваши "примеры". Выражаясь вашими же словами, вы бы хоть цитировали нормально. Ваши "примеры" вообще никакого отношения к теме не имеют, потому что ни "коллоид", ни "андроид" (также как "алкалоид", "гуманоид", "астероид", и т.д.) транслитерациями с английского не являются. "-оид" в них образован от греческого "εἶδος". Тот факт, что в английский (и в кучу других языков) они тоже были заимствованы не делает английское слово источником русского. А Pink Floyd только подтверждает мое наблюдение.

Comment: Хорош пургу гнать! Высокомерием там и не пахло. Зачем предлог-то пропускать? Обязательно надо выдумать какое-то высокомерие или ещё что-то, где его и близко нету, и начать враждовать со мной.))

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой: Ну, значит, показалось. Все, извиняюсь, и уже перестал враждовать. :-) Но примеры все равно не подходят.

Comment: )) Наверно, вы правы, что они из греческого и не подходят поэтому. Проще вам поверить, чем разбираться.)

Answer (score 2):

Можете припомнить русское слово, оканчивающееся в именительном падеже на **-ойн**? Видимо, при данном заимствовании русская традиция словообразования оказывает корректирующее действие (где "во**и**н", там и "коин" быть достоин).

Будь это слово фамилией, вышло бы иначе (важнее было бы прямое и обратное соответствие), но оно образовано из обычных корней. Даже в формальной *транслитерации* нет строгости на все времена; например, та, что с русского, изменялась недавно в России и имеет отличия от принятой в США. А *практическая транскрипция* в разное время тяготела то к фонетике (*Уотсон, Мор*), то к формальной транслитерации (*Ватсон, Стрейзанд, Мур*).

Comment: Модет, это и вправду из-за конечного "н"? Я знаю, что нормы транслитерации периодически меняются. Но ведь для таких дифтонгов в настоящее время "й" как раз и является нормой! Кроме этого загадочного (для меня) `биткоин`, я не могу припомнить ни одного другого примера с "и" вместо типичного "й".